# How to create a rucursive timeout function

Tags: javascript, timeout

I'm trying to build a recursive timeout function with JavaScript. The function should recursively run until it's completed, multiplying the timeout by 1.5 each time the conditions are not met.

So far, this is what I have but it's not working atm. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var condition;

function doSomething(arg) 
{
    if (window.condition === true)
    {
        recursiveTimeout(arg, 3500);
    }
    else 
    {
        doSomethingElse(arg);
    }
}

function recursiveTimeout(arg, time)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (window.condition === true)
          {
             var newTime = (time * 1.5);
             recursiveTimeout(arg, time);
          }
          else 
          {
             doSomethingElse(arg);
          }
    }, time);
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: last recursiveTimeout(arg, time); Shouldn't that be newTime?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a little bit for it to run in jsFiddle :

```
var condition = true;

function doSomething(arg) 
{
    if (condition === true)
    {
        recursiveTimeout(arg, 100);
    }
    else 
    {
        doSomethingElse(arg);
    }
}

function doSomethingElse(arg){
    console.log("Doing something else" + arg);
}

function recursiveTimeout(arg, time)
{
    console.log("Recursive waiting" + time);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (condition === true)
        {
            var newTime = (time * 1.5);
            if (newTime > 2000) condition = false;
            recursiveTimeout(arg, newTime);
        }
        else 
        {
            doSomethingElse(arg);
        }
    }, time);
} 

doSomething("x");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75Lmvn2n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a comment already called out the biggest issue, you are always setting it to 3500 since you aren't using the newTime variable.

See it working in a pen here.
http://codepen.io/justindunham/pen/tvnKz

```
var recursiveTimeout = function(arg, time) {
  console.log('recursiveTimeout(' + time + ')');
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if (window.condition == true) {
             var newTime = (time * 1.5);
             recursiveTimeout(arg, newTime);
          }
          else {
             doSomethingElse(arg);
          }
    }, time);
}
```